# .Net RegEx match pattern "aebecea" / "aebeceb"/ "aebecec" / "beceaec"

Tags: .net, regex

I have .Net Regex ([abc][e])+([abc]) but when I try to match, it matches only few characters and not the whole string in a group.

Here is my input and desired output groups

- aebeceaxyz - Group 1 (aebece), Group 2 (a)
- aebecebxyz - Group 1 (aebece), Group 2 (b)
- aebececxyz - Group 1 (aebece), Group 2 (c)
- beceaecxyz - Group 1 (beceae), Group 2 (c)

In my Regex, I am getting the result of (ce)(a)/(ce)(b)/(ce)(c)/(ae)(/c) which is not what I want.

Comment: What do you want to get? I can't understand your logic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the first match of [abc][e] in the first group, but you want to wrap some parens around the entire group you're capturing. Also, you can use ?: to make the inner group non-capturing. This should give the result you're looking for:

```
((?:[abc][e])+)([abc])
```

Answer (score 0):

try `([abce]{5}[e])+([abc])`

the regex you are trying does not specify number of repetitions in the first group

you can also just have `([abce]{6})+([abc])` unless you really want to make sure the first group ends with 'e'

Comment: I believe he is trying to make it so that he does not have to specify the number of repetitions in the first group, in which case my answer should do just that.

Comment: good point, this will get you correct matches but it assumes your input is consistent to the patterns you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ([abc][e]).*([abc]) maybe?

Comment: THe .* syntax is greedy and would simply capture the rest of the string, leaving just a single group with 2 letters.